# ASP.Net MVC route to account name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

There are some similar and even same questions but I would like share what I want to do because I still struggling with this.

In general I would like to allow user to switch accounts. Switching process should be done from URL also. Example if user type this URL www.domain.com/accountname it should be redirected to account which he provided. I partially did this functionality but I am not able to complete this entirely.

I would like to satisfy following requirements:

1. If user provide URL without account name it should navigate to account page where user must choose some account.Example of that URL is: www.domain.com/controller/action
2. If user supply wrong account name or account name where he does't belong he should be redirected to appropriate controller and appropriate action.
3. If user provide correct account name and where he has access he should be redirected to Account controller and SwithByName action.
4. Once user provided account name it should always displayed in browser's URL.

I am trying to achieve this in RoutesConfig where I added one more custom route.

Here is my defoult route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "SomeController", action = "SomeAction", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Before default route I added my custom route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "AccountRoute",
            url: "{accountName}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "SwitchByName", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Configurations which I supplied above works properly but without satisfying forth requirement.

Example if I provide www.domain.com/account it will redirect me to that account and it works. But if I click somethig else from menu it will redirect me and display URL in browser like this: www.domain.com/controller/action. This is not what I expected, I would like to se something like this: www.domain.com/account/controller/action. If I manually supply following URL www.domain.com/account/controller/action it will throw exception.

Can you please give me any suggestions for RoutingConfig?

I also tried with filters but it seems to me that is more correct way to achieve this with routing.

Thanks

Comment: What version of MVC?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `accountName` instead of `id` as your defaults declaration.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "AccountRoute",
    url: "{accountName}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "SwitchByName", accountName = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

And declare `accountName` as argument for your MVC action method.

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult SwitchByName(string accountName)
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Account name: "+ accountName;

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried with this but it doesn't work for me. If I use "accountName" with default parameters it will hit "SwithByName" action and it is good. When request came to "SwithByName" action with accountName=null some logic should redirect to another to specific page. That part does't work properly because it again redirect to "SwitchByName" action and it became infinity.

Comment: @ivan.petrovic Have you added default routes and 'AccountRoute' in your Route configuration ? Because it work on my implementation.

Comment: Yes, I have default route. I will provide update when I fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "AccountRoute",
            url: "{accountName}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "SwitchByName", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { accountName="Regex";/*minimum 1 char*/ }
        );

public ActionResult SwitchByName(string accountName)
    {
        //use accountName;

        return View();
    }
```